# Best quadrature formula for integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am looking for the best formula for integrating the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}P_5(x) $$

Where $P_5(x)$ is a generic polynomial of degree 5.

I was thinking of using Hermite formula, but it only works with the boundary of the integral between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, I tried to play around a bit with integration extrema but without avail.

I also tried to use Laguerre integrals but the problem is that if I fix the $x^2$ I have a square root inside the polynomial!

Could I have a hint?

Comment: should be trapezoidal.

Comment: Keep in mind that this type of integral can be calculated analytically in terms of gamma functions.

Answer (score 1):

By parts, for $k\ge2$,
$$I_k:=\int_0^\infty x^ke^{-x^2}dx=-\left.\frac{x^{k-1}}2e^{-x^2}\right|_0^\infty+\frac{k-1}2\int_0^\infty x^{k-2}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{k-1}2I_{k-2}.$$

Then

$$I_1=-\left.\frac{e^{-x^2}}2\right|_0^\infty=\frac12$$ and

$$I_0=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$ by the known formula.

This is enough to integrate for any polynomial.